# Is it possible in java program to read class files in jar present in maven repository without downloading

Tags: java, maven, jar

Is it possible in java program to read class files in jar present in maven repository without downloading. I need the methods and class names of the jar present in the pom file of maven.But is there any way i get to list out all the methods and class available for the jar specified in pom file without downloading the jars

Comment: Sure! First [summon the Jedi Council](http://assets.gocomics.com/uploads/blogs/blog_image_4367_10162_WuMo_By_Wulff___Morgenthaler_Mar_13__2017_201710311652.jpg) - how are you going to get the pom in the jar without getting the jar? First, get the Jedis together... they can use the force!

Answer (score 0):

No.

You need to read these classes/methods from somewhere. There is no separate pre-compiled metadata in the Maven repo, so the only way to get this information is to actually have the class files. Which come in a JAR. Which you have to download.